# Google Maps iOS sdks get error: Background execution would crash in this scenario

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to add a map to my custom keyboard extension. After I tried to add MKMapView in the keyboard, I get immediately crash when the map view showed up. So I am trying to add google map to the keyboard. But out of luck, I am getting error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSBackgroundAppException', reason: 'Background execution would crash in this scenario'`

I copied the exact code from google maps documentation, and I ran this code in another blank project, and it worked. But it just won't work in the custom keyboard extension. It gives me the error above. If you still want to see the code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Comment: Do keyboard extensions run in the background? Google Maps SdK for iOS needs to be in the foreground for OpenGL to work correctly.

Comment: @Brett No. I added the google map view in view controller's view.

Comment: Can you supply a complete sample for repro? Attach to a new bug on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Bug

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?

Comment: @digitalPad No. I just gave up using google maps iOS in keyboard extension.

Comment: Having the same problem here... does anybody found a solution? I'm using cocoapods.